# Problem using qsort() with 3D arrays of char

Tags: c, icalendar, qsort

I'm making a C program that disassemble a .ics file for future plans, and stores it in a array. So I'm making a 3 dimention array that contains every lines for every VEVENT it finds in the file ;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 85
#define LINE_STRING_SIZE 80
#define NB_PARAMETER 12

int cmpfunc(const void* pa, const void* pb){
    /* Comparison function for qsort();
    /* Expected : sort entire array by DTSTART line
     * which strcmp() can do between two elements
     */
    const char *a = ((const char ***) pa)[0][2];
    const char *b = ((const char ***) pb)[0][2];
    return strcmp(a,b);
}

int main(int nbArgs, char *arg[])
{
    //Opening file
    FILE* cal = fopen(arg[1], "r");
    if (cal == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    //Counting number of "BEGIN:VEVENT" lines
    int eventNB = 0;
    char ligne[LINE_STRING_SIZE];
    while(strncmp(ligne, "END:VCALENDAR", 13) != 0){
        fgets(ligne, LINE_STRING_SIZE, cal);
        if(strncmp(ligne, "BEGIN:VEVENT", 12) == 0){
            eventNB++;
        }
    }
    rewind(cal);
    //Array creation
    char tabLigne[eventNB][NB_PARAMETER][MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    //Repositionning at first "BEGIN:VEVENT"
    while(strncmp(ligne, "BEGIN:VEVENT", 12) != 0){
        fgets(ligne, LINE_STRING_SIZE, cal);
    }
    int indexLigne = 0;
    int indexEvent = 0;
    while(strncmp(ligne, "END:VCALENDAR", 13) != 0){
        while(strncmp(ligne, "END:VEVENT", 10) != 0){
            strcpy(tabLigne[indexEvent][indexLigne], ligne);
            indexLigne++;
            fgets(ligne, LINE_STRING_SIZE, cal);
            //In case of DESCRIPTION overflow to next line :
            if(indexLigne == 7 && strncmp(ligne, "UID", 3) != 0){
                int previousLineSize = (int)strlen(tabLigne[indexEvent][indexLigne-1])-2;
                for (int k = previousLineSize; k < previousLineSize+(int)strlen(ligne)-1; k++){
                    tabLigne[indexEvent][indexLigne-1][k] = ligne[k-previousLineSize+1];
                } 
                
                //strcat(tabLigne[indexEvent][indexLigne-1], ligne);
                fgets(ligne, LINE_STRING_SIZE, cal);
            }
        }
        strcpy(tabLigne[indexEvent][indexLigne], ligne);
        fgets(ligne, LINE_STRING_SIZE, cal);
        indexEvent++;
        indexLigne = 0;
    }
    //Sorting (what doesn't work like I want it to)
    qsort(tabLigne, eventNB, sizeof(tabLigne[0][2]), cmpfunc);
    
    //Just displaying
    for (int i = 0 ; i < eventNB ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 12 ; j++){
            printf("%s", tabLigne[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

With a file that looks like this ;

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//ADE/version 6.0
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220206T080021Z
DTSTART:20220228T100000Z
DTEND:20220228T113000Z
SUMMARY:Evenement 4 -rf
LOCATION:117
DESCRIPTION:\n\nIF S2 TD2\nHGLEP LDTEB QS\n(Exporté le:06/02/2022 09:00)\n
UID:ADE604955542d56616c656e63652d323032312d323032322d313033392d302d34
CREATED:19700101T000000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20220206T080021Z
SEQUENCE:-2091234875
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20220206T080021Z
DTSTART:20220302T143000Z
DTEND:20220302T160000Z
SUMMARY:Evenement 89 -hg
LOCATION:101
DESCRIPTION:\n\nIF S2 TP2C\nABBY KDJEUTBDOLSP\n(Exporté le:06/02/2022 09:
00)\n
UID:ADE604955542d56616c656e63652d323032312d323032322d3937362d302d32
CREATED:19700101T000000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20220206T080021Z
SEQUENCE:-2091234875
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Now I want to sort all of thoses VEVENT by their DTSTART caracteristic (stored in tabLigne[x][2], which I can use strcmp() to do between two elements). Problem is I have no idea how qsort() works, keep getting "segmentation fault (core dumped)" and I've spent weeks trying to make it work.

Comment: To make sure that your sorting works as intended (and make it much easier to debug) I suggest you create a new program to just get that part to work. Hard-code an array in that new program, and make it a proper [mre].

Comment: Does the program "work" if you don't call `qsort` (just that the records are out of order)?

Comment: What does `sizeof(tabLigne[0][2])` evaluate to, and can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an array of arrays of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer to a pointer.

While it's true that arrays decays to pointers (to their first element) that decay doesn't propagate. You also have to remember that `qsort` passes pointers to each element in the array.

So the `qsort` function will (effectively) call your `cmpfunc` similar to:

```
cmpfunc(&tabLigne[0], &tabLigne[1])
```

Since each element of `tabLigne` is an array of arrays (type `char [NB_PARAMETER][MAX_STRING_SIZE]`) then a pointer to an element will be `char (*)[NB_PARAMETER][MAX_STRING_SIZE]`.

That's the type you need to use for the cast inside the function:

```
const char (*a)[NB_PARAMETER][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = pa;
const char (*b)[NB_PARAMETER][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = pb;

return strcmp((*a)[2], (*b)[2]);
```

---

You also pass the wrong element size to the `qsort` function.

Tbe element size (the third argument to `qsort`) should be the size of each element in `tabLigne`. And that size is gotten by `sizeof tabLigne[0]`.

Comment: I will need some time to perfectly understand how exactly pointers work in this case, but still a huge thank for this solution !